# Why a raw listening socket on port 255 keeps opening up and closing in random interval?

Tags: networking, command-line, server

A random listening raw socket keeps opening up and closing in random intervals on port 255.

Running "ss" in the shell with this line, when I was testing for something else :

```
sudo ss -eoinlp state fin-wait-1
```

gave me this output:

```
Netid   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port  Process         
???     0       0       0.0.0.0:255         0.0.0.0:*          ino:46774389 sk:6c99 <->
```

What can it be since "Netid" and "Process" don't show anything, pid or process name or anything.

Comment: You could probably catch it with `sudo watch lsof -i:255` OR grab the port yourself (e.g. wirh `nc` or `perl`) and see what fails.

Comment: I tried to grab the port but it opens and closes so fast. I did not metion that I used "while true;do sudo ss -eoinlp state fin-wait-1;done" to see for how long it stayed open, but it closes really fast,